# rosout node and rosout topic

Tags: ros, rosout, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to wikiros tutorials and my ros textbook, the node `rosout` subscribes to the topic `/rosout`, takes the messages, records them in a textual log file.

My inference from this explanation is some nodes publish some messages to the topic `/rosout`, and the node `rosout` records them in log file. In this point, a question comes to my mind:

which nodes publish messages to the topic `/rosout` ?

Can any node publish a message to the topic `/rosout` ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314400/rosout-node-and-rosout-topic/) by [gktg1514](https://answers.ros.org/users/37700/gktg1514/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2019-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can any node publish a message to the topic `/rosout`?

Sure: every node can publish to any topic

> which nodes publish messages to the topic `/rosout`?

Any node using any of the [`ClientLibraries`](http://wiki.ros.org/Client%20Libraries) (which means: every).
Check out [this section](http://wiki.ros.org/rosout#Client_APIs) as well as the links. There it is detailed how ROS logging (e.g. using `rospy.log*` and `ROS_*` end up in `/rosout`).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3